# Highlight Active Achor tag in asp.net using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

i am trying to change color of the list on clicking anchor tag using jquery. On clicking the anchor tag i have called a C# function code behind.. if i give return false code in jquery like the below code the color has changed. but code behind function is not working. once i comment return false from jquery the code behind code is working but the  color has not changed.

jquery code:

```
<ul class="ullist" id="navlist">

    <li id="list1"><a id="a1" runat="server" onserverclick="lnkactive_click" style="width: 10px; position: relative">Active</a></li>

 <li id="list2"><a id="a2" runat="server" onserverclick="lnkabeyance_click">Abeyance</a></li>

</ul>
```

Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("a").click(function () {

        $("li.active1").removeClass("active1");

        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active1');

        return false;
    });

 });
```

Comment: page reloads and changes from js gets back to default state of the page, so having `return false;` is necessary.

Comment: Styling a link that *is about to change the page URL* is pointless.

Comment: i am using this for filter purpose. when i click one link it filter records of gridview and i want to know which is clicked by the color

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the colour change in your code behind ( in 'lnkactive_click') because the postback will re-render your HTML thus losing any changes you make client-side.